# How to create an API with a "remember me" function in Flask?

Tags: python, api, authentication, flask

I'm going to build an API in [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for a (to be created) app which will be built using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). In the API many calls will need authentication.

To get into the topic I was reading [this tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/restful-authentication-with-flask) on creating authentication for a Flask-built API. In this tutorial they first show how a user can use basic password authentication for every call, after which token based authentication is introduced.

As far as I understand, the client who calls the API should simply get a token and authenticate every subsequent call with that. In the meantime, the client should keep track of time and either get a new token every 9 minutes (before the old token expires) or simply keep on calling with the token until the client gets an `Unauhorized Access` message. **Am I understanding this correctly?**

Moving on, I wonder how it works with Apps on which you login on your phone and then are always logged in whenever you open the app (like for example the Facebook app). This is obviously more convenient to the user than always needing to provide the username/password and I would like to implement something like that as well. I wonder though; **how is a permanent logged in feature like this implemented on the server side? Is it done by providing the password and username for every call, or using a never expiring token, or yet a different way?**

All tips are welcome!

Comment: OAuth is what you are looking for. Facebook generates you an OAuth token which gives you permanent access, it does 'regenerate' itself every so often. Not the token on Facebooks side. You can then revoke this from your account within Facebook.

Comment: @JoeDoherty - The thing is that I'm not after access to Facebook. I just want to build an API that remembers the users that are logged in.

Comment: What's wrong with sessions?

Comment: Why not to use Flask-Login which has already this feature?

Comment: @kramer65 I was not talking about Facebook just using an example. That is how Facebook implements it. You can do it anyway you want. Sessions will work.

Answer (score 0):

I've done what you want to do with:

- Flask-security https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/:

  To manage users and permissions.
- Flask-oauth-lib https://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/:

  Provide oauth functionnality.

So, you have to take a look at Oauth flow, implements a user backend (like Flask-security) and implements an oauth server (with flask oauth lib for example) and bind it to your user backend.

After that, it's oauth standard flow. You just have to give the right token on each api calls   and TADA !

With this way you can also, if you want, give access to your api to third-party app thanks to oAuth :)